# PhotoSphereViewer: <a href="…"> not working on touchscreen

Tags: javascript, iphone, three.js

I made a simple page with the "PhotoSphereViewer" library and i want to add a couple of links, with the "Markers Plugin".

http://klappfon.info/xxxemanuel/2/

It works like a charm on firefox and safari, but unfortunately not at all on touch screens / phone browsers...

The links seems "clickable" (turning to active state, red) but does not open...
My theory is that it has something to do with the navigation of the sphere since link does open when "PhotoSphereViewer" is set to "TwoFingerMode"...

Any ideas how to work around that?

THANKS!!!

```
plugins:    [PhotoSphereViewer.GyroscopePlugin, 
            [PhotoSphereViewer.MarkersPlugin,{markers:[{
                    id: '1',
                    className: 'link',
                    longitude: 0.7,
                    latitude: 0,
                    html: '<a href="http://google.com">1234</a>',
                    anchor: 'bottom right',
                    scale: [0.5, 1.5],
                    style: {
                      maxWidth: '200px',
                      color: 'white',
                      fontSize: '30px',
                      fontFamily: 'Helvetica, sans-serif',
                      textAlign: 'center',

                      },
                    }, 
                  ]
                }]
              ]
```

Comment: What does the console say? :p Did you know you can connect your chrome browser on your android phone to your computer's browser to check the developer console? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

Comment: unfortunately i dont have an android phone ....

Comment: That is unfortunate. I don't know enough about that library to help :/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add links to html markers because the click is intercepted. Instead you should attach custom `data`to the marker and use the `select-marker` event.

https://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/plugins/plugin-markers.html#select-marker-marker-data

```js
const viewer = new PhotoSphereViewer({
   plugins: [PhotoSphereViewer.GyroscopePlugin, 
            [PhotoSphereViewer.MarkersPlugin,{markers:[{
                    id: '1',
                    className: 'link',
                    longitude: 0.7,
                    latitude: 0,
                    html: '1234',
                    anchor: 'bottom right',
                    scale: [0.5, 1.5],
                    style: {
                      maxWidth: '200px',
                      color: 'white',
                      fontSize: '30px',
                      fontFamily: 'Helvetica, sans-serif',
                      textAlign: 'center',

                      },
                    },
                    data: { href: 'http://google.com' },
                  ]
                }]
              ]
});

const markersPlugin = viewer.getPlugin(PhotoSphereViewer.MarkersPlugin);

markersPlugin.on('select-marker', (e, marker) => {
  window.location.href = marker.data.href;
});
```